# Do R modeling packages treat variables that are unordered factors the same as character variables?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have categorical variables that are character columns. Will R modeling packages correctly handle them as nominal categorical variables even if I leave them as character columns, or do these packages require them to be unordered factors?

Comment: You should do so.

Comment: R has remarkably few inconsistencies for a collection of programs written by many authors. However,  in my experience it is always a good idea to declare categorical variables as factor variables. 'Getting by' without this declaration in one R procedure is no guarantee you can safely omit it in another.